# IE7 issue - spacing too large on floated, padded elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Having IE7 only issues with spacing on this page: http://chantalorganics.co.nz/wordpress/newsletter/

The image below shows the large space above and below the feature boxes, and above the footer content.

I can see that many people have issues with margins in IE7, but I am using padding. I am also using Eric Meyer's reset.css. However, the content is floated which seems part of the problem.

Appreciate any guidance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this big blank space is because of margin-bottom added to 'entry-content' class. This class is added to div right under H1. You can remove that margin-bottom and add it to H3 with 'Find out why' text. In my case that solved problem :)

Btw. on Chrome when You hover on Tahini Cookies image the image move's down. That is weird...

EDIT:
To repair footer blank space add in styles display inline-block like below

```
#footer-container { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Big blank space above footer is because You have height added to #primary-menu and #container. I tried to remove that but then I noticed that after that menu is not height enough so I modified both heights to min-height: 563px (number is up to You). Is that what You are expecting?
I found help at http://www.cssnewbie.com/double-margin-float-bug/

And today I don't have that wierd jumping Tahini Cookies image. Can You tell me what was that and how did You repaire this?

Comment: Thanks Robert, but removing the `margin-bottom` from `entry-content` didn't change the space below the white boxes and at the top of the black footer. And yes, that image moving in Chrome is very weird! Further investigation required...

Comment: I edited my answer. Try that :)

Comment: Thanks again Robert! That fixes the footer spacing on the shorter pages, but then take a look at the 'Top products' page... As for the weird image, it was an absolutely positioned image accidentally placed inside a `<p>` that Chrome didn't like.

Comment: Actually, it works fine, just conflicts with a script I will probably remove. Thanks!